# Rails BDD Unable to find visible xpath "/html" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

selenium-webdriver

when I try to do integration test I fail at this assertion:

```
@user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
@client = FactoryBot.create(:client, user: @user)
@event = FactoryBot.create(:event, client: @client)
visit client_path(@client)
click_link "Bill"
```

and get this error

```
 And an invoice is created to the client                  # features/step_definitions/new_invoice_steps.rb:9
  Unable to find visible xpath "/html" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
  ./features/step_definitions/new_invoice_steps.rb:12:in `"an invoice is created to the client"'
  features/new_invoice.feature:15:in `And an invoice is created to the client'
```

Here is the link code

```
<%= link_to "Bill", bill_client_path(@client), method: :post%>
```

This is the method I call which is in the client controller

```
def bill

#some code here

  respond_to do |format|
    if invoice.save
      flash[:success] = 'Invoice was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to invoice}
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: invoice }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
  end
```

When I stop just after the link click with byebug and type current_url it gave me this

```
"http://www.example.com/clients/1/bill"
```

which don't have a view because the bill method is intended to redirect to the invoice view. Capybara is stuck at that page and of course gave me a blank page.
Why Capybara doesn't get the second redirect?
How I fix this?

Test log

```
    Started POST "/clients/1/bill" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-18 15:54:55 +0100
Processing by ClientsController#bill as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mClient Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = ? AND "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mEvent Exists (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "events" WHERE "events"."client_id" = ? AND "events"."billed" IS NULL LIMIT ?[0m  [["client_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
No template found for ClientsController#bill, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 210ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara? What Capybara configuration settings are you using? What are you doing before clicking the link? Also show the stacktrace that goes with your error.  See - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Odds are it's because your POST link is being interpreted as GET due to not requiring 'capybara/rails' or an error in your JS is preventing the UJS code from initializing.  Impossible to tell without more info though.

Comment: Added more informations

Comment: If you are actually using `selenium-webdriver` for this test (it's opening firefox/chrome browser window, etc) then it's most likely you have an error in your JS that is preventing rails ujs from initializing properly and therefore the click_link is generating a GET rather than a POST.  Check your test.log to verify the type of request being made.

Comment: There was indeed an error in my js but correcting it dind't solve the problem. Actualy I use cucumber to do tests, so there aren't browsers tab being opened, it's all in the background. Where I ca find the log file?

Comment: Ok, I solved. The redirect code was inside an if statment that didn't pass.. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Cucumber will still open browser instances etc if using selenium-webdriver and you haven't configured it to run chrome or firefox in headless mode.  If you haven't configured to run headless browsers, and it's not opening a browser instance, then you're not using selenium and are probably using rack_test (which doesn't support JS) to run your tests.  If you have configured headless then it's often good to disable that when trying to debug since you can then see what the browser is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need DatabaseCleaner gem since transactional fixtures do not work with Selenium. If you use framework Ruby on Rails add the database_cleaner gem to the :test group of your Gemfile and put the following code into spec/rails_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  # Use transactions by default
  config.before do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  # For the javascript-enabled tests, switch to truncation
  config.before :each, driver: :selenium do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after :each, driver: :selenium do
    load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"
  end

  config.after do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

In spec file use 'describe' with specific driver:

```
describe 'something', type: :feature, driver: :selenium do
  ...
end
```